# Can you run Windows Live Movie Maker on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, compatibility, windows-movie-maker

Can you run Windows Live Movie Maker on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not

From the [system requirements](http://download.live.com/SystemRequirements):

> Operating system: Windows XP with
>   Service Pack 2 (32-bit edition only),
>   Windows Vista (32-bit or 64-bit
>   editions), Windows 7 Beta (32-bit or 
>   64-bit editions), or Windows Server
>   2008. **Note: Windows Live Movie Maker is not supported on Windows XP**

Comment: "not supported" doesn't (necessarily) mean "won't run".  It means there's no one to call if you have problems.

Answer (score 3):

From [**The future of Windows Live Movie Maker**](http://windowslivewire.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!2F7EB29B42641D59!41131.entry)
by *Windows Live Movie Maker team*.

> **You’d like to use Windows Live Movie Maker on Windows XP**.
>   Given the technical requirements, unfortunately we won’t be able to support Windows XP at this time. But **[Windows Movie Maker 2.1](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/updates/moviemaker2.mspx) for Windows XP is still a great option if you’re still using Windows XP**. As we mentioned in our initial post about Windows Live Movie Maker last October, we’ve built a new engine for Movie Maker that makes use of some of the latest and greatest technologies available on the Windows platform.  Introduced in Windows Vista (and supported in Windows 7) is a new graphics driver model, which brings more reliable and stable support for high-end graphics. We’ve also built our new engine on top of DirectX, which improves speed and enables even more advanced capabilities over time. Finally, we’ve also built Windows Live Movie Maker on top of the new Windows 7 Scenic platform (and have brought it to Windows Vista as well) which makes our new user interface possible.